# checking the request response in a while loop

Tags: python

I am sending multiple request to a website using `grequests` module. I want to check if the response is what I want because sometimes the server does not reply correctly. The response is a simple string.

This is a sample of one of the urls:
http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/instinfofast.aspx?i=22811176775480091&c=39+

I want to check the length of each response and the length of all the responses that I get. I tried the following code:

```
def online_data():
    while True:
        try:
            l = []
            rs = (grequests.get(u, timeout = 1) for u in urls)
            requests = grequests.map(rs)
            for response in requests:
                l.append(response.text.split(','))
                response.close()
            for i in l:
                if len(i) > 13:
                    break
            for i in l[:14]:
                if i:
                    break
            if len(l) == len(symbols):
                break

        except AttributeError:
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    return l
```

But I am not sure whether I am doing it right or not.

In the if statements I want to check if the response that I get is what I want and if it is not, I want to repeat the function from the start of the while loop.

Comment: What does the `rs` function do?

Comment: Hard to tell if this checks if the response is what you want, since we don't know what you want.

Comment: @Barmar I just want to know how to check if the response that I get is what I want. The If statements is my conditions. the length of each response must be over 13 and the lengh of all the responses must be equal to length of `symbols` which I didn't mention here

Comment: If the response isn't what you want, the loop ends because of `break`. If you want to retry, use `continue`.

Comment: You can use `raise AttributeError` to go to the `except` block and it will sleep and retry.

Comment: @Barmar where should I use `continue` instead of `break`? Is it the correct way to check the responses using the `for` loop and `if`?

Comment: Change ALL the `break` to `raise AttributeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retry whenever the response doesn't meet your conditions, you should `raise AttributeError` so that you go to the `except` statement, instead of breaking out of the loop.

```
def online_data():
    while True:
        try:
            l = []
            rs = (grequests.get(u, timeout = 1) for u in urls)
            requests = grequests.map(rs)
            for response in requests:
                l.append(response.text.split(','))
                response.close()
            for i in l:
                if len(i) > 13:
                    raise AttributeError
            for i in l[:14]:
                if i:
                    raise AttributeError
            if len(l) == len(symbols):
                raise AttributeError

        except AttributeError:
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    return l
```